# Java Spark MLlib: There is an error "ERROR OWLQN: Failure! Resetting history: breeze.optimize.NaNHistory:" for Logistic Regression in ml library

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, logistic-regression, apache-spark-ml

I just tried to use Apache Spark ml library for Logistic Regression, but whenever I tried it, there was an error message, such as

"ERROR OWLQN: Failure! Resetting history: breeze.optimize.NaNHistory: "

The example of data set for logistic regression is following:

```
+-----+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
|state|dayOfWeek|hourOfDay|minOfHour|secOfMin|     features|
+-----+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
|  1.0|      7.0|      0.0|      0.0|     0.0|(4,[0],[7.0])|
```

And there is code for the logistic regression as following:

```
//Data Set
StructType schema = new StructType(
new StructField[]{
    new StructField("state", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("dayOfWeek", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("hourOfDay", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("minOfHour", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("secOfMin", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty())
});
List<Row> dataFromRDD = bucketsForMLs.map(p -> {
    return RowFactory.create(p.label(), p.features().apply(0), p.features().apply(1), p.features().apply(2), p.features().apply(3));
}).collect();

Dataset<Row> stateDF = sparkSession.createDataFrame(dataFromRDD, schema);
String[] featureCols = new String[]{"dayOfWeek", "hourOfDay", "minOfHour", "secOfMin"};
VectorAssembler vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featureCols).setOutputCol("features");
Dataset<Row> stateDFWithFeatures = vectorAssembler.transform(stateDF);

StringIndexer labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("state").setOutputCol("label");
Dataset<Row> stateDFWithLabelAndFeatures = labelIndexer.fit(stateDFWithFeatures).transform(stateDFWithFeatures);

MLRExecutionForDF mlrExe = new MLRExecutionForDF(javaSparkContext);
mlrExe.execute(stateDFWithLabelAndFeatures);

// Logistic Regression part
LogisticRegressionModel lrModel = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(maxItr).setRegParam(regParam).setElasticNetParam(elasticNetParam)  
// This part would occur error
.fit(stateDFWithLabelAndFeatures);
```

Comment: did you get the answer, now I have this Error.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same Error. It comes from [breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/99f399288177450ae12e7a565e9c38c8991e445a/math/src/main/scala/breeze/optimize/FirstOrderMinimizer.scala#L85) ScalaNLP package which Spark is just importing. It says something about the derivative is not able to be produced.

I'm not sure what this means exactly, but in my dataset i could argue that with less data i was using the more often the error was thrown. Meaning that a higher portion of missing features for a class to be trained on, the error happened more often. I think that has something to do with not being able to optimize correctly because of the missing information for a class.

Nontheless, the error does not seem to stop the code from running.